# Get CSV values on a pandas rolling function

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I am trying to get a csv output of values for a given window in a rolling method but I am getting an error `must be real number, not str`.

It appears that the output must be of numeric type.
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23002

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(1,10)})
df.head(10)

# Output
    a
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   7
7   8
8   9
```

**Tried:**

```py
to_csv = lambda x: x.to_csv(index=False)
# to_csv = lambda x: ",".join([str(d) for d in x])
df["running_csv"] = df.rolling(min_periods=1, window=3).apply(to_csv) # <= Causes Error

# Error:
# TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

**Expected Output**

```py
    a   running_csv
0   1   1
1   2   1,2
2   3   1,2,3
3   4   2,3,4
4   5   3,4,5
5   6   4,5,6
6   7   5,6,7
7   8   6,7,8
8   9   7,8,9
```

**Question**: Is there any alternative way to get the CSV output like shown above?

Comment: Further fine-tuned my solution both to simplify it and to enhance it to use only fast vectorized functions.  Take a look!  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```py
>>> df['running_csv'] = pd.Series(df.rolling(min_periods=1, window=3)).apply(lambda x:x.a.values)
>>> df
   a running_csv
0  1         [1]
1  2      [1, 2]
2  3   [1, 2, 3]
3  4   [2, 3, 4]
4  5   [3, 4, 5]
5  6   [4, 5, 6]
6  7   [5, 6, 7]
7  8   [6, 7, 8]
8  9   [7, 8, 9]
```

From here, further processing should be easy enough.

Comment: I think OP wants text, you can add `.apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))` to your pipe.

Comment: For a complete solution see the post by @SeaBean which actually takes the array to a CSV.

Answer (score 2):

While it would be great to be able to do this using:

```
df['a'].astype(str).rolling(min_periods=1, window=3).apply(''.join)
```

as you mentioned, rolling currently [does **not** work with strings](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23002)

Here is one way:

```
(pd.DataFrame({i: df['a'].astype(str).shift(i) for i in range(3)[::-1]})
   .fillna('')
   .apply(','.join, axis=1)
   .str.strip(',')
)
```

output:

```
0        1
1      1,2
2    1,2,3
3    2,3,4
4    3,4,5
5    4,5,6
6    5,6,7
7    6,7,8
8    7,8,9
```

Answer (score 1):

Riding on the incomplete/partial solution by @fsimonjetz, we can complete it to generate the CSV values, as follows:

```
df['running_csv'] = (pd.Series(df.rolling(min_periods=1, window=3))
                                 .apply(lambda x: x['a'].astype(str).values)
                                 .str.join(',')
                    )
```

or further simplify it and enhance it **to all vectorized functions**, as follows:

```
df['running_csv'] = (pd.Series(df['a'].astype(str).rolling(min_periods=1, window=3))
                                                  .str.join(','))
```

Now, we have turned all (slow) `.apply()` and `lambda` functions to only (fast) vectorized functions.

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   a running_csv
0  1           1
1  2         1,2
2  3       1,2,3
3  4       2,3,4
4  5       3,4,5
5  6       4,5,6
6  7       5,6,7
7  8       6,7,8
8  9       7,8,9
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.rolling` doesn't work if the output is not a numeric. Multiple issues exist on github. However, it's possible to get the outcome:

```
to_str_list = lambda x: ','.join(x[x.notna()].astype(int).astype(str).values.tolist())

df['running_csv'] = pd.concat([df['a'].shift(2), df['a'].shift(1), df['a']], axis=1) \
                      .apply(to_str_list), axis=1)
```

```
>>> df
   a running_csv
0  1           1
1  2         1,2
2  3       1,2,3
3  4       2,3,4
4  5       3,4,5
5  6       4,5,6
6  7       5,6,7
7  8       6,7,8
8  9       7,8,9
```